# Get Code Page from wchar_t string

Tags: c++, wchar-t, codepage-437

Is there a way to get the code page given a string in a given language?

Example:

```
TCHAR *str = "你好";
int codepage = GetCodePage(str);  // Should return 936 Chinese Simplified.
```

Comment: That is just an array of bytes.  How would a system assume what those bytes represents?

Comment: Heuristics can help here. I know no C++ library but the `chardet` Python module can do a great job in guessing the charset (Python name for code page) of a text. Maybe you could read its documentation... (just google for it if you do not know it)

Comment: Heuristics can result in false/unexpected results, though, so be careful.

Comment: You basically have to implement heuristics for this. If you can limit it to a few codepages, like UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32, it's fairly easy to guess (based on the presence or absence of certain bytes), but when you go to legacy and local codepages, you need to go all-out with a chardet-like solution.

Comment: And the method would be quite different if TCHAR is wchar_t or char. In the former case, you have just to examine which charsets contain all the existing unicode codes and use the more common (ASCII if only 7 bits, Latin1 if only 8 bits). In the later, only heuristics can help